# Como ocultar um checkbox do materialize CSS pelo css

Tags: css, materialize

Estou com um problema, não estou conseguindo ocultar um elemento utilizando apenas o  display:none em um checkbox do framework materialize.

Tentei desta forma:

```
  .listaPerfil input{
    display: none;  
  }
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código. Busque fazer um [mcve].

Comment: O materialize utiliza um label para criar a aparência do checkbox, ou seja você tem que da display:none no label do checkbox também.

Comment: seria assim?
label input{ display:none}

Comment: Sim, com seus respectivos ids

Answer (score 1):

O materialize é composto por dois elementos:

O input que é o elemento em si

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test5" />
```

E o label que é a parte visual do elemento

```
<label for="test5">Red</label>
```

Então uma solução é ocultar o que envolve estes dois elementos.

Vamos pegar este caso que esta na documentação deles:

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test5" />
  <label for="test5">Red</label>
</p>
```

Vamos colocar uma classe na tag p

```
<p class="meucheck">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test5" />
  <label for="test5">Red</label>
</p>
```

E o css ficará assim:

```
.meucheck{
    display:none;
}
```

Ocultando o elemento por completo.

Você também pode utilizar de class já pronta do materialize, veja este link na parte 'Hiding/Showing Content', que mostra todas as opções.

http://materializecss.com/helpers.html

Comment: Entendi, mas preciso ocultar apenas o checkbox

Comment: Mas isso vai ocultar o checkbox, porque o materialize utiliza o label para mostrar a parte visual do checkbox, ou seja o checkbox de verdade já esta oculto, inclusive se você ocultar só o label já vai funcionar. Abra a pagina aperte com o botão direito e clique em inspecionar elemento no checkbox, você vai ver que ele na verdade é um label.